# Método SendEmailAsync não é executado

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Debugando vi que o método *SendEmailAsync* do *controller Account* não é executado e não retorna erro, ele simplesmente é ignorado, todos o paramentos estão corretos *userId*, *code* e *protocol*.

```
string code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);  
var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);  
await _userManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirmar sua conta", "Confirme sua conta clicando <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">aqui</a>");
```

alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Não coloque foto dos seus códigos, pois caso precisemos testar teremos que redigir tudo do zero, para que possamos reproduzir seu problema copie seu código e coloque-o em um bloco de código clicando em [Editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/244487/edit)

Comment: obrigado pela correção.

Answer (score 0):

Para isso você deve implementar a classe SendEmail que esta assinada com a interface ISendEmail, aproveite e veja a injeção de dependência.
Com isso deve resolver seu problema.

Comment: Resolvi injetando o IIdentityMessageService no AccountController, e resolvendo a dependência com simple injector. Sendo assim, pude usar a classe  EmailService  com o método SendAsync para enviar email de confirmação.

Comment: Se estiver utilizando o novo template do Core é so implementar a classe, se fazendo isso resolveu ótimo. Cavalaria!!!